# How to print 4 odd pages per sheet (in front), and 4 even pages (in back)?

Tags: 20.04, printing, pdf

I have a PDF file (with 8 pages), I want to print it in the following way:

- It must be 4 pages per sheet,
- The odd pages must be printed together, same for the even pages

So, we have these pages (1, 2, 3, 4, ..., 8) that must be printed in one paper (both sides).

The odd pages must be printed as shown below:

```
+-------+-------+
|       |       |
|   1   |   3   |
|_______|_______|
|       |       |
|   5   |   7   |
|       |       |
+-------+-------+
```

The even pages must be printed (in the back of the paper) as shown below:

```
+-------+-------+
|       |       |
|   4   |   2   |
|_______|_______|
|       |       |
|   8   |   6   |
|       |       |
+-------+-------+
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, and qpdfview software to view and print the pdf file.
I got the following message: ***Options "Pages Per Sheet" and "Page Set" cannot be used together. Please turn one of those options off.***

Is there any solution ?

Thanks

Comment: You can use the Boomaga (virtual) printer driver to arrange the pages: print them one by one to Boomaga. Ref: https://www.boomaga.org/

Comment: Thanks @FedonKadifeli. Actually, the file has 1312 pages, I mentioned 8 pages just for easy explanation

Comment: About boomaga - I have never used it, but it as packaged - see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Boomaga .

Answer (score 1):

i would use pdftk for the job, because it can do some pretty nice things: it can count the pages, burst the pdf and combine the pdf...

1. get $PAGECOUNT `pdftk really_big.pdf data_dump|grep NumberOfPages`
2. burst the big pdf. for each site a single pdf. `pdftk really_big.pdf burst`

> Actually, the file has 1312 pages

so you will get 1312 pdf files with step 2 (:

3. merge -`pdftk page1.pdf page2.pdf page3.pdf cat output newfile.pdf` 
   simply write a shell script, which counts your pattern [1,3,5,7,4,2,6,8] up to your $PAGECOUNT and print the pagecount into the merge code. finally all your 1312 pages will be combined in your patttern into a single pdf, which can be printed on every printer like so:
4. print - `lp -d $PRINTERNAME newfile.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Rearrange the page order in the PDF file so that they print in the correct order using "Pages per sheet"

I use PDFarranger (it's in the Ubuntu repositories / Ubuntu Software application) for rearranging PDF pages, but there are others too.

Comment: Thanks @user535733. Actually, the file has 1312 pages, I mentioned 8 pages just for easy explanation

Comment: Gee, that would have been good to know in the Question....

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @leisefuxX,

My solution was to split the PDF file into 2 separate files: odd pages in the 1st file, and the even pages in the 2nd file. Then, I printed each one.

I used `pdftk`, and below the codes that I used:

```
pdftk A=BigFile.pdf cat Aodd output odd.pdf
pdftk A=BigFile.pdf cat Aeven output even.pdf
```

Comment: You printed odd.pdf and even.pdf. How? The technique you used seems rather essential to achieve the needs you stated in your first post. Odd and even pages printed as shown.